# Postgresql return variable in type stored in a table

Tags: postgresql, types, composite-types

I'm currently developing an app and encountered a problem when trying to create a query on a table that uses a custom type.

Here is an example table and type,

```
CREATE TYPE address AS (
  street varchar(40),
  city   varchar(25),
  zip    varchar(5)
);
CREATE TABLE houses (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  address address
);
```

I need to retrieve a list with all the cities stored in the table houses.
Here's what I tried to do:

```
SELECT address.city
FROM houses
GROUP BY address.city
```

It detects address.city as a table. Is there any way to do what I want to do in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use a compound type like that in a table. But you can still do this, use parenthesis.

```
SELECT (address).city
FROM houses
GROUP BY (address).city
```

From [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html)

> To access a field of a composite column, one writes a dot and the field name, much like selecting a field from a table name. **In fact, it's so much like selecting from a table name that you often have to use parentheses to keep from confusing the parser.**

Instead, I would use a `jsonb`. Or, if you're going to use a compound type you should use [`stdaddr`](http://postgis.net/docs/stdaddr.html) from PostGIS.

Comment: I would not suggest json in place of normalization.

Comment: It's not normalized either way.

Comment: I'm curious why jsonb is preferred over a compound type. Are there performance considerations?

Comment: @HaleemurAli there are a few, they cut both ways. there is no gist index on custom types. The exercise is left for the implementer so you're limited to btree or indexing the sub-types manually.